# Vue, how to test if child component (which is shown via v-show) is visible or not

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-component, vue-test-utils

I'm trying to figure out how to test (using vue test utils & jest) whether a Child Component (which is shown via `v-show`) is currently visible or not (irrelevant of the Child Component's contents).

My vue html code looks like:

```
<ChildComponent v-show="isShowing"/>
```

I can't figure out how to test it. I came across this: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/327#issuecomment-355501127 however, `wrapper.findComponent(...).hasStyle is not a function`.

The closest that I can think of is testing the boolean:

```
expect(wrapper.vm.isShowing).toBe(true)
```

I know how to test if it was using `v-if`:

```
expect(wrapper.findComponent(ChildComponent).exists()).toBe(true) //it is conditionally rendered
expect(wrapper.findComponent(ChildComponent).exists()).toBe(false) //it is not conditionally rendered
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to test, by using [isVisible](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#isvisible) method.

`isVisible()` method check if the `display:none` or not and also it can test `visibility:hidden` and `opacity :0`

Here is an example with your code:

```
expect(wrapper.findComponent(ChildComponent).isVisible()).toBe(true)
```

And if that component is the main wrapper, then use like this:

```
expect(wrapper.isVisible()).toBe(true)
```

Comment: Hi Riyaz, thanks for answering. When I try this code I get: ```TypeError: wrapper.findComponent(...).isVisible is not a function```

Comment: @Clarity I belive it has issue with getting childComponent element, use the `wrapper.find('.class-name-comp').isVisible()`

Comment: @Clarity and if that component is the main wrapper, then use like this: `expect(wrapper.isVisible()).toBe(true)`

Comment: does anyone know how to do this when you have a transition animation? I've tried adding a setTimeout (which passes but it also passes before the animation has finished so it's wrong), and have used await, nextTick and a few other things but nothing has worked. Maybe it isn't possible but it would be interesting if it does

Answer (score 0):

The same happened with me, and is solved it by creating a [jest setup file](https://jestjs.io/pt-BR/docs/configuration#setupfiles-array), as an `index.js` file inside `test/unit` with the following code:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.use(IconsPlugin)

Vue.config.productionTip = false
```

And after that I added the following to `jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  ...    
  setupFiles: ['./tests/unit/index.js']
  ...
}
```